# Captcha php to js validation

Tags: php, javascript, captcha

I have written in php I want to write this code, but there is an error in the function onclick javascript

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["captcha"]))
{
    if($_POST["captcha"]==$_SESSION["code"])
    {
    echo "Correct";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Not Correct";
    }
}
?>
```

**Javascript**

```
function ja_k2filter_submit()
    {
    var captcha = $('captcha');
        var code = $('code');
        if ($code = '');
        {
            alert("Güvenlik Kodunu Doğrulayınız!");
        }
                return false;
        if ($code = captcha);


        if($('input_searchword'))
        {

            input = $('input_searchword');
            v_label = ($$('label[for=input_searchword]')[0].innerHTML)+'...';
            if((input.value !='')&&(input.value!=v_label))
            {
                $('mod_ja_searchword').value =input.value;
            }   
        }
```

javascript values ​​but does not

Comment: I don't really unterstand what your code is supposed to do, but are you sure you want that "return false;" after the first if?

Comment: Oh my god! Well, it's a start. Did you write this code, or did you copy paste a couple things together from different sources?

Comment: Like @Chris said..  the return false will ALWAYS run.  Move it inside the if block.  if ($code = captcha); Does nothing. input = $('input_searchword');  should probably be var input = $('input_searchword').val();  .... etc etc

Comment: I wanted to do something to use this php code: <?php

if(isset($_POST["captcha"]))
{
    if($_POST["captcha"]==$_SESSION["code"])
    {
    echo "Correct";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Not Correct";
    }
}
?>                                 in javascript function